# Can I open a native Play store app inside my app? I don’t want my app to go to background

Tags: android

Can I open a native Play store app inside my application? I don’t want my application to go to background.

Comment: You want to open a native PlayStore app inside your own native PlayStore app??

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you CANNOT open a native Play Store app without sending your to background. You can use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), but this is a whole different thing.

Comment: More generally, you cannot embed the UI of one app in another app, outside of very constrained scenarios (e.g., app widgets and a home screen).

Comment: I agree, yet I was quite horrified by the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using webview. Just load url of application in your application's webview.

Comment: The OP is inquiring about the "native Play store app". That is probably not referring to the Play Store Web site.